# Workspaces not working after I turned it on

Tags: workspaces

I enabled workspaces from Appearance in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, tried to do the Ctrl Alt Left/Right to switch workplaces but it doesn't seem to work. I tried restarting my computer which didn't work. Checked the shortcut settings in the keyboard to make sure everything was right that Ctrl+Alt+Left/Right is still the shortcut and it is. Even right clicking a window, it doesn't say "move this to left/right workplace".

This started after I reinstalled Ubuntu. I recently reinstalled Ubuntu after trying to dual-boot Windows alongside it, and now this doesn't work. I have disabled Unity, I'm using Gnome. It worked before when I disabled Unity for Gnome as well.

Tried to be as detailed as possible, let me know if you need more thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Switched from GNOME (Compiz) to GNOME (Metacity) and it worked. You do that from the login screen.